# What's the Difference Between OBDII adapters and Toyota Mini VCI?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii

I've been researching Toyota diagnostic connectors, and ran across something called a Mini VCI adaptor meant for use with [Toyota's TechStream software](https://www.toyota-tech.eu/GTS/Wizard/Step5-Software.aspx).  The physical interface looks like a standard OBDII and [according to this advertisement](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2014-Latest-version-V8-30-021-MINI-VCI-Interface-FOR-TOYOTA-TIS-Techstream-V8-30-021/672381461.html) it supports the following protocols:

- K-Line ISO 9141
- KWP 2000 ISO 14230-4
- SAE J1850 PWM
- SAE J1850 VPW
- CAN 2.0B ISO 11898
- CAN ISO 15765-4

On the face, this just looks like a standard OBDII adapter.  Am I missing something?  Couldn't I just use a standard OBDII adapter with the TechStream software?

Comment: Well, it works with standard protocols, so I don't see why not as long as the protocol for your car is supported by the cable you choose. Probably just a rebranded standard cable.

Comment: I tried to use a standard OBDII USB and it wouldn't connect using the software so I'm assuming that the OBDII USB cable needs to be a Mini VCI J2534.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's a [J2534 device](http://www.boschdiagnostics.com/pro/j2534-faqs). These support reflashing with the proper software. I've used the OpenPort 2.0 another J2534 device with the TechStream software before I assume this is the same just made in China.

Generic OBD2 cables don't support reflashing as they're missing the necessary chip.

Comment: So if I'm not planning on reflashing any ECU proms, I could just use a standard OBDII adapter with the TechStream software?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes I believe it has to be J2534 compatible. This website https://obdtoolshop.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/toyota-tis-techstream-which-cable-is-the-best/ shows the Mini VCI cable you mentioned as confirmed to work with TechStream.

Answer (score 2):

Only copied Toyota Techstream software (latest Ver. 12.30.017) works with [Mini VCI](http://www.obdii365.com/wholesale/mini-vci-for-toyota-with-toyota-tis.html) J2534 pass-thru. I don't think original Techstream can work on clone cable. 
But the clone cable and Techstream crack does work. Not bad, I can change things on my 4runner very easily. As a note, which is not specified anywhere else that I have seen, you can perform a Zero Point Calibration using this tool, I had some issues with VSC lights coming on, and was able to do the ZPC with this and cleared them out. I would recommend this tool to anyone who owns a Toyota vehicle. I am not sure what models it works for buy I know Tacoma and 4runner are supported.